# Getting a run time error for C++ project

Tags: c++

I have to write a program for a C++ class and I am having a bit of trouble. I have gone through all my variables and I feel like I initialized everything, but its still not working.

Program parameters: Calculate electrical bill. Customer gets charged $0.27 a kwh up to 500 kwh, then is charged at an extra rate of $0.57 a kwh thereafter.

*Input: kwh*

*output: Total customer bill*

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //List the variables
    double kwh;
    double baseKwh;
    double extraKwh;
    double baseBill;
    double extraBill;
    double electricBill;

    //User inputs the kwh used
    cout << "Enter kwh used: "; //Prompt
    cin >> kwh;

    //Process the data and compute the bill
    if (kwh <= 500) {
    baseKwh = kwh;
    extraBill = 0;

    }
    else {
    baseKwh = 500;
    extraKwh = kwh - 500;
    }
    baseBill = baseKwh * 0.27;
    extraBill = extraKwh * 0.55;
    electricBill = baseBill + extraBill;

    //Output the bill.
    cout << "Your bill is $" << electricBill << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

problem:

> Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'extraKwh' is being used
>   without being initialized.

Microsoft Visual Studio points to line 30 as the problem. The program works fine when the user inputs above 500, however, when the user inputs 500 or below then I get the error message.

Comment: What if `kwh < 500`? Answer: extraKwh is not initialized and will likely be some garbage value.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: The code is confusing because it has too many variables. For example, `baseBill` and `extraBill` aren't needed; `electricBill = baseKwh * .027 + extraKwh * 0.55` works just fine.

Comment: I agree with you @PeteBecker unfortunately this is for a class, and these are variables the teacher has specified needed to be in place. I too feel like it could be much less convoluted.

Comment: @YourBrainOnJazz - fair enough. I suppose the goal is to clarify the process.

Comment: @YourBrainOnJazz, if you're happy with the proposed answers, you should really mark one of them with a tick :)

Answer (score 2):

```
extraBill = extraKwh * 0.55;
```

Well if the `else` clause is not evaluated above this code, `extraKwh` is indeed uninitialized. So you are trying to read value of uninitialized variable above and triggering [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Assign some default value to it during declaration and that issue should go away.

In general it is good idea to initialize variables during declaration.

Comment: Thanks! @Giorgi I think this and syco_link fixed it for me!

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your variables, but left them *uninitialized*.

You are using `extraKwh` no matter what happens in your code. Judging by your logic, you should initialize it to zero at the same time it is declared:

```
double extraKwh = 0;
```

This way, there will always be a value assigned to `extraKwh`, even if you don't don't hit your `else` block.

Comment: Thanks @syco_link I think this and Giorgi's comments fixed it!